# Is it possible that a view list entities that are not related to other (like a not in (select ...) )?

Tags: 7, views

I have been trying to build a view to list entities A that are **not related** with entities B.

Entities A are users. Entities B are submissions. I need to list users that don't have submissions for a certain year.

In SQL it would be: `select uid from users where uid not in (select uid from submissions where year = NNNN`).

Is there a way to do this using Drupal 7 and Views 3?

Comment: Untested but what if you add a relationship and don't check require this relationship. Then use filters to filter where year != NNNN OR year IS NULL.

Comment: Thanks rooby. I tested it, but that filter won't work, since it looks for other years, but doesn't check for the wanted year.

Ie: Let's suppose I search for users with NO submissions for **2014**. If **user John** has submissions for **2014** and also for other years (*2012*, *2013*), he will be listed, and I only need users that don't have submissions for 2014.

Comment: I would expect year != 2014 AND year NOT NULL would work. NOT NULL is not empty in the views UI.

Comment: Thanks rooby. I expected it would work too! but unfortunately, it seems to be more complicated than I thought :( The filter you proposed does not check for the wanted year itself, so if **John** **has** submissions for **2014** and also has submissions for *2013* that filter applies (*year != 2014 AND year NOT NULL*), and he will be listed. But I want to list all users that *don't* have submissions for the wanted year (regardless their submissions for other years)

Comment: Oh oops, I was getting a little confused. I would have though my original: year != NNNN OR year IS NULL would work, but it depends on the join type that views is using for your relationship I guess.

Comment: can't you just do it in the filters? set up your submissions relationship, then add a filter for the submission date field. in the filter relationship, link it to the submissions relationship. then in the filter operator, select a standard option or use regex. if that doesn't work, you can do the subquery via the views_view_field module and pass the uid in from the parent view.

Comment: Thanks for your comment murraybiscuit! The filter rooby suggested (year != YYYY) means **get the users related with submissions in years != YYYY**, but those users may also have submissions for YYYY. I want to **bring users that don't have any submission for YYYY**.

Answer (score 0):

Views is a simple query builder, it's UI doesn't really support this out of the box.

I recommend looking at [Views Custom Conditions](https://drupal.org/project/views_custom_conditions):

> This Views Custom Conditions module facilitates the site administrator
>   to inject custom conditions into a views query. ‘Views’ is a powerful
>   and highly flexible module that provides website builders with
>   critical list making abilities. It generates a dynamic SQL query
>   according to views construction for displaying data. So, adding a one
>   more step to filter your data as per your requirement, this module
>   will really be helpful.
>
> This module adds the condition specified by the site admin to any
>   views where clause with the existing conditions implemented by views
>   itself in conjunction with AND operator.

Also if you want to do custom calculations on Fields see [Views Raw SQL](https://drupal.org/project/views_raw_sql) or [Views Calc](https://drupal.org/project/views_calc).

Comment: Thanks tenken! I tried those modules but I couldn't find a way of resolve my simple problem.

Comment: well if you know how to code just alter the sql query Views uses using php in a custom module ... :) but i was trying to help by giving you an Admin UI to do this.